# Dynamic 'for-loop' Structure

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I cannot wrap my head around the following, say I have a List, each list contains a 'would be' for loop. each succession should be within one another.

So if I have a list with 3 objects, I want

```
class Focus {
    String focus;
    List<String> values;

    public Focus(String focus, String... values) {
        this.focus = focus;
        this.values = Lists.newArrayList(values);
    }
}

List<Focus> focuses = new ArrayList<Focus>();
focuses.add(new Focus("Focus 1", "09", "14", "13", "12"));
focuses.add(new Focus("Focus 2", "94", "92"));
focuses.add(new Focus("Focus 3", "A", "B"));

String my_string = "";
for (Focus obj1 : list_obj_x) {
    for (Focus obj2 : list_obj_xx) {
        for (Focus obj3 : list_obj_xxx) {
            my_string += obj1 + " " + obj2 + " " + obj3;
        }
    }
}
```

obviously with a list the for-loop structure can grow, and the above is not possible.
i need a dynamic structure to cater for the `my_string` need. i.e:

```
94    09    A
94    14    A
94    13    A
94    12    A
94    09    B
94    14    B
94    13    B
94    12    B
92    09    A
92    14    A
92    13    A
92    12    A
92    09    B
92    14    B
92    13    B
92    12    B
```

the output should be like the above.
this is what I have so far:

```
int focusCount = focuses.size();
for (int i = (focusCount - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    Focus currentFocus = focuses.get(i);
    List<String> currentFocusValues = currentFocus.values;

    for (int cfv = 0; cfv < currentFocusValues.size(); cfv++) {
        String currentFocusValue = currentFocusValues.get(cfv);

        for (int j = (i - 1); j >= 0; j--) {
            Focus previousFocus = focuses.get(j);
            List<String> previousFocusValues = previousFocus.values;

            for (int pfv = 0; pfv < previousFocusValues.size(); pfv++) {
                String previousFocusValue = previousFocusValues.get(pfv);
                System.out.println(currentFocusValue + " " + previousFocusValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it caters for all combinations of the list values, 
but not in the structure I want.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: IMO you need to write a recursive function, to go one level down for each of the "Focus" arrays.

Comment: or implement a method for printing single Focus object (or overide toString()), this way you can iterate only through Focus object, each calling your eg. print() or toString() method printing the line with all arguments.

Comment: @epoch - Can't you use a StringBuffer instead of a String to dynamically populate the results of your iteration? Also, while dealing with collections such as List<T>, it might be a better idea to use an 'enhanced-for' loop to get the values of your collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward approach would probably be recursion. In each step of the recursion, you "pin down" the value of the n-th list one by one, then recurse down the "list of lists" until you reach the end.

```
String[] values = new String[focuses.size()];
CreateCombinations(focuses, 0, values);
```

With the recursive method

```
private void CreateCombinations(List<Focus> focuses, int index, string[] values) {
    Focus focus = focuses.get(index);
    for (string v : focus.values) {
        values[index] = v;
        if (index < focuses.size() - 1) {
            // there is at least one other focus
            CreateCombinations(focuses, index+1, values);
        } else {
            // all values pinned down
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(values[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < values.length; ++i) {
                sb.append(" ").append(values[i]);
            }
            // now do whatever you like to do with sb.toString()...
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this can be refined further, but maybe it suffices as a starting point for you.

Comment: thank you so much, I can't believe I missed such an easy approach

Comment: Please note that I left out checks against index-out-of-bounds and null reference conditions for the sake of brevity, you might want to add them to prevent exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an iterative approach (needs cleaned up still):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Focus {
    String focus;
    List<String> values;

    public Focus(String focus, String... values) {
        this.focus = focus;
        this.values = Arrays.asList(values);
    }

    public static String printAllCombinations(Focus... focuses) {
        String myString = "";
        List<String> allCombinations = new ArrayList<String>();

        int length = focuses.length;

        if (length == 0) {
            return "";
        } else if (length == 1) {
            allCombinations = focuses[0].values;
        } else if (length > 1) {
            for (Focus f : focuses) {
                allCombinations = getCombinations(allCombinations, f.values);
            }
        } 

        for (String s : allCombinations) {
            myString += s+"\n";
        }

        return myString;
    }

    private static List<String> getCombinations(List<String> l1, List<String> l2) {
        if (l1.size() == 0) {return l2;}
        else if (l2.size() == 0) {return l1;}

        List<String> combinations = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String outerValue : l1) {
            for (String innerValue : l2) {
                combinations.add(outerValue + " " + innerValue);
            }
        }
        return combinations;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have 2 loops: 1 for the Focus-objects and 1 for their values.

Answer (score 0):

As Kurt has already mentioned, you need only two loops.

You have a list of objects, Focus object. Each object has a list of values. Therefore, you need one outer loop to go through the list of objects, and another loop to go through the list of values for the object being processed:

```
mystring = ""
int m = get the length of focuses list
for (1 through m) {
 int n = geht the length of values list for the current Focus object
 for (1 through n) {
    myString += current value;
 }

}
```