# List all possible array value combinations in specific order

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, recursion

I am quite fresh with programming and I am working on some code to generate various values for my thesis. Having spent several days searching for an answer to my problem without much success, I am hoping this community might be able to provide some insight.

**Short version**: Make the code below independent of the input array `arr`'s length.

Longer version:

I have an array of arrays, `arr = [a, b, c, d]`, as input to a function where I would like to calculate all possible combinations (i.e. `a1,b1,c1,d1`, `a2,b1,c1,d1`, etc.) without having to know the definite number of elements in `arr`.

The problem is that the results are **dependent** on each element's position in `arr`. In other words, the name of each array in `arr` (a, b, c, d) has to be able to be referenced in the results. For clarity's sake, say that `arr=[oil_price, countries, vessel_types]`. Then, it wouldn't make much sense if the results came out randomized, and not in the same order, such as:

`[ country[1], oil_price[1], vessel_type[1] ]` (first pass)

`[ vessel_type[2], country[1], oil_price[1] ]` (second pass)

The code below does take the element position in `arr` into account and creates the resultspace I would like, but requires a for loop for each element, which is what I am trying to avoid as the number of elements in `arr` could vary from time to time.

```
function resultspace(arr){
results = [];
e_id = 1;
for (count_1 = 0; count_1 < arr[0].length; count_1++){
    for (count_2 = 0; count_2 < arr[1].length; count_2++){
        for (count_3 = 0; count_3 < arr[2].length; count_3++){
            for (count_4 = 0; count_4 < arr[3].length; count_4++){
                for (count_5 = 0; count_5 < arr[4].length; count_5++){
                    for (count_6 = 0; count_6 < arr[5].length; count_6++){
                        id = e_id
                        var1 = arr[0][count_1].value;
                        var2 = arr[1][count_2].value;
                        var3 = arr[2][count_3].value;
                        var4 = arr[3][count_4].value;
                        var5 = arr[4][count_5].value;
                        var6 = arr[5][count_6].value;

                        result_instance = {id:e_id,
                                            VAR1: var1, 
                                            VAR2: var2, 
                                            VAR3: var3, 
                                            VAR4: var4, 
                                            VAR5: var5, 
                                            VAR6: var6
                                            };
                        results.push(result_instance);
                        e_id++;
                    };
                };
            };
        };
    };
return(results);
};
};
```

I have looked into recursive combination generation [here](http://hengrui-li.blogspot.no/2011/05/generate-combinations-of-elements-from.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331092/finding-all-combinations-of-javascript-array-values), but I haven't been able to take the element position of the input array into account using these methods.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I asked a very similar question once, check out the answers there (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129116/dynamic-for-loop-structure)

Answer (score 0):

1. You want names so you need to use Map instead of Array.
2. You need to provide names as Array since the order of for-in loops is not guaranteed.

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/VLj7J/. Works in modern browsers.

```
function permutate(arrays, keys, memo) {
    var options, name;

    if(keys.length ) {
        name = keys.shift();
        options = arrays[name];
        memo = memo || [{}];
        return permutate(arrays, keys, options.reduce(function(all, item){
            return all.concat(memo.map(function(curr){
                var result = copy({}, curr);
                result[name] = item;
                return result;
            }));
        }, []));
    }

    return memo;
}
```

Call it as follows

```
permutate({name: [], age: [], gender: []}, ['age', 'name', 'gender']);
```

Function `copy`

```
function copy(to, from) {
    Object.keys(from).forEach(function(key){
        to[key] = from[key];
    });
    return to;
}
```

Or an array of `{name: []}` pairs with additional preprocessing http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/VLj7J/2/.

```
function permutate(data, memo) {
    var options, name;

    if(data.length ) {
        options = data.shift();
        for(name in options){
            options = options[name];
        }
        memo = memo || [{}];
        return permutate(data, options.reduce(function(all, item){
            return all.concat(memo.map(function(curr){
                var result = copy({}, curr);
                result[name] = item;
                return result;
            }));
        }, []));
    }

    return memo;
}
```